# Symfony 2 Doctrine XML mapping and extending other classes

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I was using Doctrine 2 XML mapping in Zend framework and now find it hard to understand in Symfony 2.

The thing is, that in order to use the FOS\UserBundle my User Entity has to extend FOS\UserBundle class. But since I use Doctrine XML mapping, all the Entities are being generated automatically, which means, that I would have to manually change my User Entity code every time I update Entities.

I tried to use Inheritance mapping, but it does not work:

> Even if you specified Inheritance options in your
>    XML or YAML Mapping files the generator cannot generate the base and
>    child classes for you correctly, because it doesn't know which
>    class is supposed to extend which. You have to adjust the entity
>    code manually for inheritance to work!

So, doeas it mean, that I have to create the User Entity and all its setters and getters manually?

Here is my User.orm.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
    <mapped-superclass name="FOS\UserBundle\Model\User">
      <entity name="Nt\UserBundle\Entity\User" table="users">
        <id name="id" type="integer" column="id">
            <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
        </id>
        <field name="email" type="string" />
        <field name="firstName" type="string" column="first_name"/>
        <field name="surname" type="string"/>
        <field name="password" type="string"/>
        <field name="salt" type="string"/>
      </entity>
    </mapped-superclass>
  </doctrine-mapping>
```

Comment: Can you also share your problematic mapping xml?

Comment: Yup, I've updated the question